# My hard drive is new, but making lots of noise

Tags: hard-drive, performance

My hard drive is making noise, just like the old computers, which is strange, cause my pc is 3-4 months old. I got this one: https://www.google.com/shopping/product/7227007111886761763
Is there a way to fix that? What causes this?

Comment: Can you describe the noise? Is it a clicking? A whine? Something else?

Comment: Scratching noise, like when you run an old computer. It's not all the time.

Comment: Stop shaking it then!!

Comment: @blez If your new hard drive makes noises, and *you know they are not normal noises*, then **return it, RMA it, or exchange it!!!**  Any person who knows what a computer *is* should know what is a normal noise and what isn't.

Comment: Scratching noises are normal. Whining or clicking noises are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a quick Google search with this query (without quotes): "WD Caviar noisy" and found lots of discussions about the noise produced by the hard drive. The 'Green' variant is silent though. So I think that's the way your drive works. See: 
1

1. http://community.wdc.com/t5/Desktop/WD-Caviar-Black-is-a-loud-drive/td-p/6468
2. http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/249058-32-worry-noise-black-caviar-drive
3. According to Tech Report review of WD Caviar Black, it's the noisiest drive they ever tested: http://techreport.com/articles.x/15363/13

Answer (score 2):

Check the SMART status. Could be a bad drive or a failing motor. If it fails SMART, you probably want to contact the mfg and see if you can get it replaced under warranty.

WD makes tools to check the SMART status of their drives. Here is the link: http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=613&sid=3&lang=en

Comment: It passes the SMART status with the tool on the link.

Comment: Your sure its the drive and not a fan or something else in the system right? You may want to contact WD tech support and see if they have other suggestions. If it passes SMART most likely the drive is ok.

Comment: It's not fan and it's definitely not my SSD. I hope that it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of noise, specifically?  Those drives aren't perfectly silent to begin with, but if there are loud repetitive clicks or grinding noises or even if just the standard operating noise is deafeningly loud then there may be something wrong with the drive (in which case you should get an RMA from the manufacturer ASAP.)